# Ransack - search by two ids collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

Let's say I have following models:

```
User
  has_many :posts
Post
  belongs_to :user
```

and I have following data in the database:

```
User(id: 1)
User(id: 2)
Post(id: 1, user_id: 1)
Post(id: 2, user_id: 1)
Post(id: 3, user_id: 1)
```

I would like to build ransack search that returns users and matches following criteria:

- user has at least one post which id is in (1, 2)
- AND user has at least one post which id is in (3, 4, 5, 6).

It should return: User(id: 1), beacause he matches all criteria.

I tried to play with "Advanced mode" http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/users/advanced_search
and it is possible to define grouping criteria with two conditions, but it generates SQL with one join operation only:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id"
WHERE ((("posts"."id" IN (1, 2))
AND ("posts"."id" IN (3, 4, 5, 6))))
```

I expected something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "posts" "posts_X" ON "posts_X"."user_id" = "users"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "posts" "posts_Y" ON "posts_Y"."user_id" = "users"."id"
WHERE ((("posts_X"."id" IN (1, 2))
AND ("posts_Y"."id" IN (3, 4, 5, 6))))
```

Is it possible to achieve it with ransack?

Comment: Is this with building a search form or being filtered within the model or controller?

Comment: Post ids comes with request parameters, but the search criteria are predefined. Temorary I implemented this functionality using "join" and "where" operations, but I still use ransack criteria and would be great to combine it.